# How to Run a Batch File in a Windows Service with an API and Debug it?

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file, windows-services, vmware

I am attempting to run a batch file that utilizes the VMWare VIX API and VMRun.exe to power on/off virtual machines in VMWare Workstation. Currently my batch files work correctly when run from the command prompt. However, I can not successfully execute them from my Windows Service built in C# & .NET. I executed my batch files in my service in the following way:

```
string myBatchFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MyBatchFile");

System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processBat = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(myBatchFile);

processBat.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
processBat.ErrorDialog = true;

Process.Start(processBat);
```

I have been able to run a simple batch file that creates a text document from the service. The code for this batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
  echo Hello World>"C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\HelloWorld.txt"
```

This works as expected when executed by my Windows Service.
When I try to execute my VMWare batch file I am unsuccessful, and can not find any way to check log my output or debug it. My code for this batch file looks like this:

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=batch.log
call :LOG > %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
cd "C:\PROGRA~2\VMware\VMWARE~2\"
vmrun.exe -T ws Start "C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Virtual Machines\VM1\VM1.vmx"
PAUSE
```

I attempted to add a way for a log file to be created but nothing gets generated when I execute the batch file from the service. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the batch file is allowed to write to the `Proga~2` directory? I ask because it appears to have privilieges for running a `.vmx` file within a users profile location too!

Comment: You're right, it seems that it requires the batch file to be run as an administrator to be able to write to the `Proga~2` directory. I tried to move the .vmx file to a new directory: `C:\Virtual Machines`, but I still can not get it to power on a vm from the service or create a logfile.